# node.js, restify - handle a parameter of type array

Tags: arrays, node.js, parameters, restify

I have a node.js server with restify. I want to send it a get request that has an array of names in it. I think the request should look like this (but I am not sure about it):

```
/users?names=bob,joe,michael,joey
```

Is this query correct?

How do I get the names I send on the node.js server?

Comment: try names=bob&names=joe&names=... (not sure but I think it's the right way to achieve that)

Comment: and how do i write the function in the node server? like this: `server.get('/getDataWithNames/:names', function (req, res) { \\some stuff });`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The W3C recommendation is that one key can be repeated multiple times with multiple values:

```
GET /users?names=bob&names=joe&names=michael&names=joey
```

Good systems will be designed to handle this format of data and be able to recognize multiple keys to group them within an array.

You do not need to specify query variables in your route:

```
// perform: GET /users?names=bob&names=joe&names=michael&names=joey
server.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  // All your query vars from the GET request are in req.query
  res.json(req.query.names);
});
```

Comment: where do I find the array of the names? under req.params.users? or under req.params.names?

Comment: From a `GET` request, you can retrieve it from `req.query`. I've updated my post with some more clarification.

Comment: and names would be an array? do I get the first name by doing `req.query.names[0]` and so on?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you also test that it is an array first: `if (Array.isArray(req.query.names)) { }` as it is user input and could be omitted (resulting in `req.query.names` being `undefined`)

Comment: are you sure it's `req.query.names` and not `req.params.names`?

Comment: `req.params` only contains parameters from the URL route. We have only specified a static route for `GET /users`, query string parameters are independent of the route and are stored in `req.query`. Check out the [Express API docs](http://expressjs.com/api) for more information.

Comment: I was wondering if there's another way to pass these parameters. I'm using RESTKit in order to send this GET request, and it seems like it doesn't allow to send multiple parameters with the same name. Do you know about anything?

Comment: I cant say I know much about RESTKit, let alone Objective-C. However, this type of request is common enough that there must be a way. I would encourage you to open up a new Question here with those items tagged so someone with expertise on the subject can better assist you. :)

Comment: Thanks @SamT. I did open a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094284/ios-restkit-0-20-send-multiple-query-parameters-with-the-same-name) and I also found an answer for it :) Thanks a lot!